# Как убрать лишний текст при выводе результата парсинга?

Tags: python, парсер

Изучаю парсинг сайтов на `Python`. Столкнулся с проблемой. Решил спарсить [данный сайт](https://online.animedia.tv/top-100-anime). Хочу собрать данные по типу "русское название", "место в топе" и так далее, но как только вывожу `print` получаю ответ по типу:

> #1 Город, в котором меня нет.

Как убрать номер из названия, если они оба указаны в `span`?
А также проблема с объединением жанров. Их там несколько штук, но если использовать `find_all` не выходит вывести их текстом.

Вот код который у меня получился:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver




# options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
# try:
#     driver = webdriver.Chrome(
#         executable_path='C:\\Users\\1\\Desktop\\python\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe',
#         options=options)
#     driver.get(url='https://online.animedia.tv/top-100-anime')
#     sleep(20)

#     with open('animetop.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
#         file.write(driver.page_source)
# except Exception as ex:
#     print(ex)
# finally:
#     driver.close()
#     driver.quit()
with open('animetop.html', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
anime = soup.find('div', class_='ads-list__item').find('div', class_='ads-list__item__thumb js-postload').find('a').get('href')
anime_link = 'https://online.animedia.tv' + soup.find('div', class_='ads-list__item').find('div', class_='ads-list__item__thumb js-postload').find('a').get('href')
russian_name = soup.find('div', class_='ads-list__item').find('a', class_='h3 ads-list__item__title').text
original_name = soup.find('div', class_='ads-list__item').find('div', class_='original-title').text
tags = soup.find('div', class_='ads-list__item').find('div', class_='genre-tags').find('a')



print(tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = requests.get('https://online.animedia.tv/top-100-anime')
soup = BeautifulSoup(src.text, 'lxml')
anime = soup.select_one('.mains-container').select('.ads-list__item')
for x in anime:
    n, russian_name = x.select_one('.ads-list__item__title').stripped_strings
    original_name = x.select_one('.original-title').text
    _, *tags = x.select_one('.genre-tags').stripped_strings
    # print(n)
    # print(n[1:])
    print(russian_name)
    print(original_name)
    print(', '.join(tags))
    # print(*tags, sep=' ')
    print('-'*40)

Город, в котором меня нет
Boku dake ga Inai Machi
Приключения, Психология, Сёнэн
----------------------------------------
Ванпанчмен
One-Punch Man
Боевые искусства, Комедия, Повседневность, Приключения, Фантастика
----------------------------------------

...

Врата: Там бьются наши воины
Gate: Jieitai Kanochi nite, Kaku Tatakaeri
Комедия, Мистика, Приключения, Фэнтези
----------------------------------------
Призрак в доспехах: Синдром одиночки
Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex
Детектив, Киберпанк, Фантастика
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: `.select_one('div.js-postload').select_one('a').get('href')` или `.select_one('.js-postload').a.get('href')` или `.select_one('a')['href'])` или `.find('a')['href']` итого: `anime_link = f"https://online.animedia.tv{x.a['href']}"`. За подробностями обратитесь к документаций, есть на русском https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.ru/bs4ru.html